# How to change the color of scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of the scrollbars on my pages in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

This code creates scrollbars:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 750px; height: 400px">   
</div>
```

To change their color, I tried this code:

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">

BODY
{
scrollbar-base-color: orange;
scrollbar-arrow-color: green;
scrollbar-DarkShadow-Color: blue;
}
</STYLE>
```

The above code is in my header, but it didn't change the scrollbars' color.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please dont change the color of my scrollbar, it's part of the browser chrome, and is already skinned to match my operating system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as others said, the CSS you posted won't work on modern browsers (IE8, Safari, Firefox, etc).  Since you're trying to scroll a div, you do, however, have the option of making a custom scrollbar in Javascript/DHTML.  A quick Google search reveals a few have done just that like this one: http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Answer (score 12):

For Chrome and Safari you can change the scrollbar style using this code:

```
/* Chrome, Safari */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
background-color: #C2D2E4;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
height: 30px;
background-color: #0A4C95;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just copy and paste after head for

1.rounded corners style

```
<style type="text/css">
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 6px; height: 4px; background: #ffffff; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #000000; -webkit-border-radius: 1ex; }
</style>
```

2.square corners with border style

```
<style type="text/css">
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 9px; height: 3px; background: #FFFFFF;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background-color:#ffffff ; border: 1px solid black;}
</style>
```

you can change the color for code [click here](http://html-color-codes.info/) or [here](http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm)

Answer (score 3):

That code only works in Internet Explorer. Are you testing in Firefox or Safari by chance?

Comment: It *only* works in Internet Explorer 5+ and has apparently been discontinued in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

It works in IE5 to 7. It has been discontinued in IE8. Safari recently gave support for it using different css properties I believe.

There are usability concerns with changing the scrollbar colour.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for the div, code the scrollbar colors in that class, then apply it to the div. You are not changing the scrollbar colors on the browser, only the div you are creating. Your div would be `<div style="overflow: auto; width: 750px; height: 400px" class="className">    </div>`

In your class you would create the scrollbar colors using the applicable scrollbar part names, i.e. scrollbar-face-color and so on. To find out which code applies to which area of the scroll check http://iebar.discoveryvip.com/, or you can search on the web, there are a number of places for that.

Answer (score 1):

This code was easyer just paste after

> < h e a d >

```
<style type="text/css">
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 6px; height: 4px; background: #ffffff; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #000000; -webkit-border-radius: 1ex; }
</style>
```

Comment: It seems the OP was interested in a background color, not background image.

Comment: it worked, able to change the background and scroll bar color with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
*, html {
scrollbar-face-color: #FF0000;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #0000FF;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #00FF00;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FF00FF;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #00FFFF;
scrollbar-track-color: #FFFF00;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #000000;}
```

Comment: This will only work on IE6, and 7.  Not IE8, Firefox, Safari, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here


html,body{
     scrollbar-face-color: #414340;
            scrollbar-shadow-color: #cccccc;
            scrollbar-highlight-color: #cccccc;
            scrollbar-3dlight-color: #cccccc;
            scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #cccccc;
            scrollbar-track-color: #cccccc;
            scrollbar-arrow-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can change color of scrollbar using javascript also. There are various components in scroll bar like base color, face color, arrow color etc that changes color of various parts of scroll bar. The following lines might help you.

```
document.body.style.scrollbarBaseColor = "colorname";
document.body.style.scrollbarArrowColor = "colorname";
document.body.style.scrollbarTrackColor = "colorname";
```

Apart from the above styles, you will have scrollbarShadowColor, scrollbarHighlightColor, scrollbar3dlightColor,scrollbarDarkshadowColor etc. So, choose your component of scroll bar and change the color of it.