# Change colors of scrollbar elements

Tags: html, css, colors, scrollbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the color of scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997645/how-to-change-the-color-of-scrollbars)

I need to change the default colors of the elements of a scrollbar. I'm referring to the scrollbar that gets displayed if you have a div with overflow: auto; for example.

So far I've tried these CSS rules, but I don't know if they represent a rather old way of doing things:

```
<style type="text/css">
 body {scrollbar-3dlight-color:;
            scrollbar-arrow-color:;
            scrollbar-track-color: ;
            scrollbar-darkshadow-color:;
            scrollbar-face-color:;
            scrollbar-highlight-color:;
            scrollbar-shadow-color:}
</style>
```

Any push in the right direction would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: See this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997645/how-to-change-the-scroll-bar-color

Comment: Do you need this to work in all browsers? I think setting scrollbar colours is only supported in IE, unless you somehow roll your own (as done in some parts of Facebook, for example).

Comment: http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar This could be of some help to you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is not W3C valid CSS, it will only work with some browsers, namely IE? Here's a [JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adamish/NzkTJ/). Note the CSS properties are against the div, not the body.

CSS

```
div.scroll {
    scrollbar-base-color: red;
    scrollbar-face-color: red;
    scrollbar-track-color: red;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: red;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: red;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: red;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: red;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: red;
}​
```

HTML

```
<div class="scroll">
content content content
content content content
content content content
</div>​
```

Comment: Only works in IE (tested FF15, Chrome21, IE8). Made it somewhat bigger, as FF and Chrome didnt show any scrollbars before my edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzkTJ/6/) IE8 only shows solid red scrollbars

Comment: @GeenHenk Not surprised, changing scrollbar colors is a terrible idea, only something microsoft would support.

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-browser solution, you need to create your own scrollbar using JavaScript, unfortunately. This gives you a lot of freedom with styling the scrollbar and each of its components, which is an upside. Here's a little demo-sample I created in case you want to take a look: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/XD4CV/1/).

I hope that helped!